# Images not showing up in html

Tags: css, image, html

I am a complete noob when it comes to web design. I just started learning some basics. At the moment I am trying to make an image become the head banner of my web page. I've visited many tutorials and each say to use the code `<img src="images/wood.jpg" height="168" width="100">` if you have a file in the directory of the webpage specifically for images and to use height and width specifiers to make it fit within the confines of the banner. With that being said i refresh the page and no image is displayed. Also bonus point for information on how to make the words overlay ontop of the image.

```
                <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <!--- COMMENT--->


            <html long="en">


            <head>

            <meta charset="UTF -8"/>
            <Title>Ken's Woodworking Emporium</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script>
                document.createElement("article");
                document.createElement("aside");
                document.createElement("footer");
                document.createElement("header");
                document.createElement("main");
                document.createElement("nav");
                document.createElement("section");
                </script>
                <![endif]-->

            <meta name="description" contents= "Learn everything you want to know 
            about wood working."/>

            <meta name="keyword" content=html5 canvas,html5,toutorial,html5 doctype,
            video, learn/>

            <meta name="robots" Content="index, follow"/>

            <base href="http://localhost/html/"/>

            <link rel= stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>


            </head>

            <body>
                <header class="banner">
                    <h1>Woodworking</h1>
                    <img src="images/wood.jpg">
                    <p> Local woodworkers</p>
                </header>

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <main>
                    <section>
                        <h2>Carpenty</h2>
                        <article>
                            <header>
                                <h3>Details on carpentry</h3>
                                <p>(Author, date)</p>
                            </header>
                            <p>THis is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                            <p>This is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                        </article>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <article>
                            <header>
                                <h3>Custom carpentry.</h3>
                                <p>(Author, date)</p>
                            </header>
                            <p>THis is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                            <p>This is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                        </article>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                    <h2>Restoration</h2>
                        <article>
                            <header>
                                <h3>Old to new</h3>
                                <p>(Author, date)</p>
                            </header>
                            <p>THis is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                            <p>This is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                        </article>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <article>
                            <header>
                                <h3>refinishing.</h3>
                                <p>(Author, date)</p>
                            </header>
                            <p>THis is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                            <p>This is the story text.This is the story text.</p>
                        </article>
                    </section>
                </main>

                <aside>
                    <h2>Have a request?</h2>
                    <p>If you have a custom order request feel free to contact us at 918-555-5555, or ABC123@yahoo.com</p>
                </aside>

                <footer>
                    <p>Footer information</p>
                </footer>

            </body>



            </html>
```

Comment: This will rely on a directly called "images" to be in the same directory as this HTML file, then in "images", a file called "wood.jpg". It's all case-sensitive, too. Do you have any errors in the browser console? That should tell you if you've referenced the wrong path or filename for the image.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an img tag, if you want the banner image as a background for some other element, you might try the background-image CSS property.  Knowing nothing about your stylesheet, I made it as straightforward as possible.

I made you a small example @ https://jsfiddle.net/wck2hyxt/1/

HTML:

```
        <body>
            <header class="banner">
                <h1>Woodworking</h1>
                <p> Local woodworkers</p>
            </header>
        </body>
```

CSS:

```
header.banner {
  background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Campania_banner_View_from_Capri.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 168px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Notice: I used an external image for the banner.  You could change that url to be "/path/to/image".  Also, I believe your intention was to make the width 100%, not just 100.

Answer (score 0):

for buttons or something with overlay you can use background image in the css as mentioned.
overwise you'll need a wrapper with attribute `position: relative` that contains the image and another div with the following as the overlay layer:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 2; // you can use higher number if needed
```

and apply absolute location relatively to the container with the attributes `top`, `right`, `bottom` and / or `left`, should look like this for the top right corner with 10px padding i.e:

in html:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="wood.jpg" alt="wood">
    <div class="img-overlay">overlay text</div>
</div>
```

in css:

```
.img-wrap {
  position:relative;
}
.img-wrap .img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

if its only inner pages that dont show up images it might because the image path is relative to last folder, better use absolute paths when or relative to the root of the website folder. like this;

```
<img src="/images/wood.jpg" alt="wood image">
```

or

```
<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/images/wood.jpg" alt="wood image">
```

or if your using wordpress it might look somthing like one of these

```
<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/**/****/images/wood.jpg" alt="wood image">
<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-content/images/wood.jpg" alt="wood image">
<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/images/wood.jpg" alt="wood image">
```

etc.

P.S for better semantics always use alt attribute with images.

Answer (score 0):

On your webserver the public_html should look like this:

- index.html
- images

The images folder above should have the file 'wood.jpg' within it.

On your local PC, right click the wood.jpg file and go to properties.
The path is case sensitive.
If the extension ends in .jpg then your code should look like this:

```
<img src="images/wood.jpg" height="168" width="100">
```

If the extension ends in .JPG then your code should look like this:

```
<img src="images/wood.JPG" height="168" width="100">
```

When refreshing, hold ctrl + F5 to clear your cache and see your changes you have made.

If you need to make words overlay the image, you will need to add position elements within your CSS. W3 provides a great tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex